# WooCommerce Admin order - Only run action if user is loaded

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, users

I am using [this plugin](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/) to switch users. I have found a snippet that allows you to switch user on the WooCommerce admin order page which is very helpful.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'ccef_order_switch_to', 99 );
/**
 * Add a switch to user link on the order details.
 *
 * @param object $order The WC Order that we're working with.
 */
function ccef_order_switch_to( $order ) {
    $user_switching = $GLOBALS['user_switching'];
    if ( $user_switching ) {
        $user        = get_user_by( 'id', $order->get_user_id() );
        $switch_link = $user_switching::maybe_switch_url( $user );
        if ( $switch_link ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $switch_link ) . '">Switch To</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to work out.., but I have no idea how to, is; only run this action if there is already a user created/loaded. The reason for this is if there is no user loaded, it stops the page from loading correctly until a user is selected, we create users on the fly when doing admin orders, this snippet breaks things if you don't have a user to switch to.

So essentially the question is - Is there a way to only run the action only if there is a user id loaded?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is check with the `get_current_user()` and check if return something, if yes, run the code. Like the example below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'ccef_order_switch_to', 99 );
/**
 * Add a switch to user link on the order details.
 *
 * @param object $order The WC Order that we're working with.
 */
function ccef_order_switch_to( $order ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_switching = $GLOBALS['user_switching'];

    if ( $user_switching && $current_user ) {
        $user        = get_user_by( 'id', $order->get_user_id() );
        $switch_link = ''; 

        // Only try to switch if a $user was set. 
        if( $user ) {
          $switch_link = $user_switching::maybe_switch_url( $user );
        } 

        if ( $switch_link ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $switch_link ) . '">Switch To</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a fatal error with this code (it may have been of fatal error before your changes). 'PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to user_switching::maybe_switch_url() must be an instance of WP_User, boolean given, called in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/domain/public/wp-content/themes/domain/functions.php on line 573 and defined in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/domain/public/wp-content/plugins/user-switching/user-switching.php:607' can you see why it would throw an error like this when no user is already created for the order?

Comment: Yes, the functions expects a user to switch to, but thats strange since my code didn't override the `$user` variable that you were using, can you put a `var_dump($user)` below  `$user        = get_user_by( 'id', $order->get_user_id() );` to see what is being printed please?

Comment: This is what it prints https://prnt.sc/g30rz0 and this is the stack trace https://codeshare.io/5w4xYx

Comment: So, the problem is here `$user = get_user_by( 'id', $order->get_user_id() );`  he is not founding any user with the given id got by `$order->get_user_id()` . How do you set this property?

Comment: I'm not sure how to work that out?

Comment: I not sure how the plugin works, but I edited my answer probably now it will prevent any errors.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help, really appreciated! Do you do freelance work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63166/discussion-between-cesar-henrique-damascena-and-nik).

Comment: Glad it worked :). Yes  I do freelance work, I moved this to a discussion chat so we can talk better.

Comment: @CesarHenriqueDamascena, It is not working in my woocommerce theme